# Manejo de herencia con Spring y JPA

Tags: java, spring, java-ee, jpa, inyeccion-de-dependencias

Buen día

Necesito crear un repositorio "B" a partir de un repositorio "A" el cual ya no debe ser modificado.  Tengo algunas dudas respecto a como proceder  ya que estoy teniendo un error de ambiguedad en mi primer intento.

Tengo mi repositorio A:

```
@Repository
public class consultasRepositorioImpl implements consultasRepositorio
{
}
```

Ahora, en el repositorio B hice lo siguiente:

```
@Repository
public class consultasRepositorioAuxImpl extends consultasRepositorioImpl   implements consultasRepositorioAux
{
}
```

Las nuevas operaciones que voy a manejar las tengo en la interfaz **consultasRepositorioAux**.

Quiero que Spring  reconozca mi clase **consultasRepositorioAuxImpl**  como un nuevo repositorio,   pero estoy teniendo el siguiente error al intentar levantar mi aplicación:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   unique bean of type [mx.repositorios.consultasRepositorio] is defined:
>   expected single matching bean but found 2: [consultasRepositorioImpl ,
>   consultasRepositorioAuxImpl]

Tengo entendido que lo anterior lo puedo solucionar utilizando la anotación @Qualifier en dónde inyecte el bean. Mi duda es, ¿no hay otra forma de resolver este problema de ambiguedad? tal vez estoy aplicando mal la herencia o las anotaciones.

se agredece cualquier apoyo

Saludos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Repository le marca al component-scan de Spring que esa clase es un componente de tu aplicación por lo que revisará al momento de crear el bean la interfaz que tenga marcada. Es decir que busca una clase que implemente la interfaz que tiene marcada. Como tiene 2 no sabe que hacer.
Efectivamente con @Qualifier resuelve el tema porque le indica explícitamente que clase debe utilizarse.

Aunque por otro lado, puede probar de hacer de consultasRepositorioImpl una clase abstracta sin marcar por @Repository y la que extiende si marcarla con el annotation.
No se como aplicaría en su caso, pero un caso que he visto es un esquema donde existe un manejo común de operaciones de ABM (un dao genérico por ejemplo) y luego las distintas particularidades de los distintos objetos de modelo se atienden con un repositorio que que extiende del genérico con las diferencias o no que este requiera. (obviamente, hay lecturas a favor y en contra de esta forma)

```
public interface GenericDao<E, I extends Serializable> {

    void save(E entity);
...
}


public abstract class GenericDaoImpl<E, I extends Serializable> implements GenericDao<E, I>

    protected GenericDAOImpl(SessionFactory sessionFactory, Class<E> entityClass) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
            this.entityClass = entityClass;
        }

        public void save(E entity) {
            //logica de guardado
        }
}

@Component
public class AlgunDaoImpl extends GenericDAOImpl<Entidad, Clave> implements AlgunDao {

@Autowired
protected AlgunDaoImpl (SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    super(sessionFactory, Entidad.class);
}
...
}
```

Desde ya que este es solo un ejemplo, y faltarían mas partes o tiene cosas como elementos genéricos para que sirva a distintas entidades.